# Match a pattern with a string and extract information

Tags: javascript, regex, date, google-apps-script

I am working on a Google Apps Script. I want the user to enter a pattern like
`MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss`

According to the pattern I want to extract information from a string. The string is like `02/29/2016 07:00:00 PM EST`. I want to extract date, month, year, hour, minute and second from this time-stamp string using the pattern given by the user.

How this can be achieved in JavaScript ?

Comment: @Mr_Green Thanks for answering but you did not get my question. The timestamp may come in a format which may not be recognized by new Date() so I don't want to use new Date()

Comment: @HariDas any example of such format? even still I think you should make the invalid format to correct format and use `new Date()` only.

Comment: @Mr_Green new Date("02/29/2016 07:00:00 EST").getMinutes() gives 30 (Probably because of timezone) which is not expected .

Comment: @Mr_Green new Date("02/29/2016 07:00:00 PM EST").getUTCHours() gives 0 which is not expected. Am I missing something.

Comment: @HariDas yes I was wrong. it is actually hard to manage different timezone times. go with momentjs.

Comment: @Mr_Green—please delete that comment, if it was an answer it would be down voted.

Comment: It seems you are after a parser, there are many already on [*GitHub*](https://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=github+javascript+date+parser&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ZfQVV5nBJ7TM8ge16YHQBg).

Comment: @Mr_Green—I meant the first one. Parsing of such non–standard strings is entirely implementation dependent, for a browser to parse it correctly depends on luck.

Comment: is https://regex101.com/r/mV3sL5/1 good?

Comment: Please search for "javascript parse date"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this example (in Google apps script):

```
var a = extractDateTimeInfo('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss', '02/29/2016 07:10:14 PM EST');
Logger.log(a);  //output: Year: 2016, month: 02, date: 29, hours: 07, min: 10, sec: 14

var b = extractDateTimeInfo('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm', '2016-12-26 16:13 PM EST');
Logger.log(b);  //output: Year: 2016, month: 12, date: 26, hours: 16, min: 13, sec: 


function extractDateTimeInfo(patt, t) {
  var YYYYPos = patt.indexOf('YYYY');
  var MMPos = patt.indexOf('MM');
  var DDPos = patt.indexOf('DD');
  var hhPos = patt.indexOf('hh');
  var mmPos = patt.indexOf('mm');
  var ssPos = patt.indexOf('ss');

  var YYYY = YYYYPos >= 0 ? t.substr(YYYYPos, 4) : '';
  var MM = MMPos >= 0 ? t.substr(MMPos, 2) : '';
  var DD = DDPos >= 0 ? t.substr(DDPos, 2) : '';
  var hh = hhPos >= 0 ? t.substr(hhPos, 2) : '';
  var mm = mmPos >= 0 ? t.substr(mmPos, 2) : '';
  var ss = ssPos >= 0 ? t.substr(ssPos, 2) : '';
  return Utilities.formatString("Year: %s, month: %s, date: %s, hours: %s, min: %s, sec: %s", YYYY, MM, DD, hh, mm, ss);
}
```

However I don't know what type of pattern given by the user you expect. But you can adapt it for other possibilities like YY etc.

You can put the result into array in extractDateTimeInfo function as well...

Answer (score 0):

This regex will work(but does not check whether the value entered by user is valid or not)

```
(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mV3sL5/1#pcre)**

*JS Code*

```js
var re = /(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/; 
var str = '02/29/2016 07:00:00 PM EST';

var result = str.match(re);
document.writeln(result[1] + '<br>');
document.writeln(result[2] + '<br>');
document.writeln(result[3] + '<br>');
document.writeln(result[4] + '<br>');
document.writeln(result[5] + '<br>');
document.writeln(result[6] + '<br>');
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/F4BTSq)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
/^(0?\d|1[0-2])\/([0-2]?\d|3[01])\/(\d{1,4})\s([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d):([0-5]?\d)$/
```

I restricted the input the most i can do :
Group 1 : Months, restricted from 0 to 12
Group 2 : Days, restricted from 0 to 31
Group 3 : Years, restricted to 4 characters

Group 4 : Hours, restricted from 0 to 23
Group 5 : Minutes, restricted from 0 to 59
Group 6 : Seconds, restricted from 0 to 59